# How to handle custom colors for Dark Mode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios-darkmode

Here is how I'm currently handling `UI Element Colors` for Dark Mode with a fallback for older operating systems.

```
extension UIColor {
    class var mySystemBackground: UIColor {
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            return .systemBackground
        } else {
            return .white
        }
    }
}
```

On this case`systemBackground` knows when it's in Dark Mode and when it's in Light Mode and it changes accordingly. I would like to do something similar using custom colors.

For instance I have a custom Yellow color that I'm currently using throughout my app and I would like to provide a different color for when in Dark Mode.

Here is the code I'm thinking...

```
extension UIColor{
    class var mySystemYellowColor: UIColor {
        // default light-color 
        var myYellow = UIColor(red: 254/255, green: 219/255, blue: 2/255, alpha: 1.0) /* #fedb02 */

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {  

            if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
                return myYellow
            } else {
                // color for dark mode in iOS 13.0
                myYellow = UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 125/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0) /* #f27d00 */
            }
            return myYellow

        } else {
            return myYellow
        }
    }
}
```

Is this an approachable way to handle custom colors for Dark Mode in iOS13 with a fallback for other operating systems?

Comment: If you can't afford to use color assets for any reason try the new color initializer. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3238041-init

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create the colors in the asset catalog.

Colors in the asset catalog can be created for different *Appearances* and can be accessed with the `UIColor(named:)` API

Please see [Supporting Dark Mode in Your Interface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/)

Comment: But I need to access the colors in code, is it possible to access the assets in code like images? Also, would it have a fallback for older operating systems?

Comment: *But I need to access the colors in code*. Why? The colors seem to be constants. In versions prior to iOS 13 only the light appearance is used in the asset catalog.

Comment: 1. Yes, just like he said, use `UIColor(named:)`. 2. No, this assumes you'll target iOS 11+, if you support lower versions, use the new color initializer in your `if #available(iOS 13.0, *)`

Comment: @Desdenova- If Understand you correctly when using Color assets in iOS11+ you don't need the fallback check, correct?

Comment: My colors are calculated in code, they're not static.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is use color assets and it has appearances set Any, Dark

And Then use asset name and UIColor(named: "AssetName")
no need any version check or check Interface Style

Answer (score 1):

I added to **Assets** additional element - **Color Set** and determined 2 colors - for Light and Dark themes (source: https://skalolaskovy.ru/xcode/556-ios-dark-theme-support-simple-implementation Russian article).
You can create some Color Sets as many as you need.